# Dock takes up 4GB of memory in Lion OS

Tags: memory, osx-lion, dock

I recently purchased an iMac, and upgraded the memory to 8GB, however, my iMac has been really laggy these days, so today, I checked the memory usage. It turned out that Dock took up 3.9G of memory, how could that be?!

Comment: have found the answer page http://superuser.com/questions/351580/very-high-memory-and-cpu-usage-by-the-os-x-dock, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not like if you use only 4GB today, you can use 12GB tomorrow. And the memory being in use has nothing to do with why your computer is laggy. If a computer is laggy, you speed it up by making it use *more* memory, not less. If your computer were using less memory, it would be slower. Otherwise, we'd remove memory from our computers to make them faster.

Comment: Being that to be the case, is it common for Dock to use up 4G of memory?

Comment: There are a few scenarios involving Adobe Updater and Parallels 6. It's also possible that you're seeing the dock using 3.9G of **virtual** memory, which is perfectly normal.